# How to deploy the current node.js development setup on my pc to a physical ubuntu server?

Tags: linux, web-applications, server

I have a node.js server app with rest api developed on my laptop right now and obviously I am able see the app on the web @ http://localhost on my laptop. Now I am trying to deploy this backend server to a physical linux server machine for further development. I will be testing on that physical server through ssh and I have already git cloned the project into the linux server. So, now how can I set it to be able to view the http responses on the web on my laptop(because currently I'm only testing @locahost)? Also how can I use api development application such as POSTMAN with the physical server from my laptop?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what OS is installed on your server ? ubuntu ?

Comment: yes Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial)

Comment: is it set to be a webserver already ? apache or nginx at least ? A domain name would probably be good to, but not mandatory. I can try writing an answer but i need to know how "ready" your server currently is, to know what you need to be up and running...

Comment: when I go to http://[server IP] right now I get a Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page. and it says, "You should replace this file (located at /var/www/html/index.html) before continuing to operate your HTTP server." How should I set this up? Sorry I'm just new to this server set up..

Comment: this is perfect. Let me write an answer. By the way do you have root access ? Or sudo privilleges ?

Comment: yes I have the root access.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, from your comments we know your server have apache installed, so that page you see when navigating to `http://[server IP]` should be a `index.html` file located at `/var/www/html/`. This is probably where you want to put your cloned files. Anything above `html/` folder is not accessible to the browser.

Of course you need `nodejs` installed. If it’s not already installed, via `ssh`, use:

> sudo apt-get install nodejs

Maybe you will need other things to install such as POSTMAN, but you'll see that installing things on ubuntu is really easy, and very well documented on the web.

Comment: so I just need to put ALL the .js files for my server app to /var/www/html/ ?

Comment: Pretty much yes.

Comment: Keep in mind that http://localhost on your local machine was pointing to a local folder, probably C:/user/... something like that. On the server its pretty much the same, with http://[server IP] pointing to  /var/www/html/

Comment: You just need to ensure you have nodejs installed, and you should be good.

Comment: No problem, have fun with developing that app !